# React select MenuItem Onchange name with event

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

in below on change handledealernameChange I want to pass {option.OrgName} also but in event I am not finding it. i want name of text. Please help i am new to it

return (

```
<Select

  className="navigation_select"

  disableUnderline

  defaultValue={

    selectedOrg === "0"

      ? info?.orgs?.find((x: { Default: boolean }) => x.Default === true)

          ?.OrgId

      : selectedOrg

  }

  variant="standard"

  onChange={(event) => {

    handledealernameChange(event);

  }}

>

  {info?.orgs?.map((option, i) => (

    <MenuItem value={option.OrgId} key={i}>

      {option.OrgName}

    </MenuItem>

  ))}

</Select>
```

);

};

passing multiple value

Answer (score 0):

A quick way around this is you can have such to render your options

```
{
  info?.orgs?.map((opt, i) => (
    <MenuItem
      value={JSON.stringify({ OrgId: opt.OrgId, OrgName: opt.OrgName })}
      key={i}
    >
      {opt.OrgName}
    </MenuItem>
  ));
}
```

And in your `handledealernameChange` function, you can destructure out the values like such.

```
const handledealernameChange = (event) => {
  // Get the selected option value
  const { OrgId, OrgName } = JSON.parse(event.target.value);
};
```